# Is there a pytorch implementation of the scipy.interpolate.griddata function?

Tags: pytorch, scipy, interpolation

I'm trying to interpolate 2D scattered data points into a regular grid of points, where the scipy function of griddata satisfies my need. But when I want to deal with larger number of points (5000+), this function becomes incredibly slow. So I want to accelerate with pytorch cuda based implementation to replace griddata, but I haven't found anything yet.. Any ideas how to implement or relevant packages?

Given certain random input data points, I want to interpolate the whole area grid like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/huAxo.png)

I expect there would be steps like:

1. find the nearest three scattered points for each point on the grid for triangulation.
2. compute the interpolated value based on the three points.